# Plot log density of a distribution in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a density in ggplot2, but using a log-scale for the y-axis.  When I do so the naïve way I end up with a line running along zero at the top of the chart and at both ends.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

**Example:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
N = 10000
DT = data.table(X = c(rnorm(N), rt(N, df = 2)), Y = rep(c("N", "T"), each = N))
ggplot(DT, aes(x=X, color = Y)) +geom_density() + scale_y_log10() + xlim(-4,4)
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Comment: do you have an example data set that we could work on ?

Comment: @biobirdman I gave an example in the question...  ...that code should be complete and run just as is.

Comment: All the examples in the [ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density.html) also form a density polygon by closing the curve with a horizontal line at y=0.

Comment: @jbaums Sorry, hadn't thought of the problem in those terms - thought it was something specific to the log scale...  after seeing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265736/1900520 I'll leave this here incase anyone else makes the same mistake